# Sigkill when renaming app

Tags: xcode, swift, sigkill

I'm all but finished developing an app. It had a project name but now that I'm about to launch it to app store I wanted to change the name. After I did that in projects file inspector, it showed me what can be renamed. I didn't deselect anything. After renaming the app I launched it and got SIGKILL error and only (lldb) in console. How could I fix this?

Comment: Although probably too late, the name of the project doesn't reflect the name in the App Store. You can put whatever you want for the name of the actual app without modifying the Xcode project's name.

Comment: yes ok but my app wont launch, so how would i be able to fix this

Comment: There's not enough information here. Have you tried cleaning the target and deleting the app from your device or simulator? Can you find a stack trace or any compiler warnings?

Comment: hey, no compiler warnings, i actually solved it, ill post an answer

Comment: I tried the same and it worked for me. Perhaps try a Clean and build again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually managed to solve it by closing xcode, right clicking myapp.xcodeproj and clicking show package contents, and then opening  pbxproj file in text editor and manually renaming all instanced where myapp name is wrong. Also had to go to storyboard and changing every view's module to correct name.

I hope this helps someone, don't forget to make a backup before going into the text file.